# Javascript convert date to Hijri

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to convert current date to Hijri.

This below is the function:

```
var fixd;

        function isGregLeapYear(year)
        {
            return year%4 == 0 && year%100 != 0 || year%400 == 0;
        }

        function gregToFixed(year, month, day)
        {
            var a = Math.floor((year - 1) / 4);
            var b = Math.floor((year - 1) / 100);
            var c = Math.floor((year - 1) / 400);
            var d = Math.floor((367 * month - 362) / 12);

            if (month <= 2)
            e = 0;
            else if (month > 2 && isGregLeapYear(year))
            e = -1;
            else
            e = -2;

            return 1 - 1 + 365 * (year - 1) + a - b + c + d + e + day;
        }

        function Hijri(year, month, day)
        {
            this.year = year;
            this.month = month;
            this.day = day;
            this.toFixed = hijriToFixed;
            this.toString = hijriToString;
        }

        function hijriToFixed()
        {
            return this.day + Math.ceil(29.5 * (this.month - 1)) + (this.year - 1) * 354 +
            Math.floor((3 + 11 * this.year) / 30) + 227015 - 1;
        }
        
        var months = ["Muharram","Safar","Rabiul Awwal","Rabiul Tsani","Jumadil Ula","Jumadil Tsani","Rajab","Sya\'ban","Ramadhan","Syawwal","Dzul Qa\'dah","Dzul Hijjah"];

        function hijriToString()
        {
            var months = new Array("Muharram","Safar","Rabiul Awwal","Rabiul Tsani","Jumadil Ula","Jumadil Tsani","Rajab","Sya\'ban","Ramadhan","Syawwal","Dzul Qa\'dah","Dzul Hijjah");
            return this.day + " " + months[this.month -1]+ " " + this.year;
        }

        function fixedToHijri(f)
        {
            var i=new Hijri(1100, 1, 1);
            i.year = Math.floor((30 * (f - 227015) + 10646) / 10631);
            var i2=new Hijri(i.year, 1, 1);
            var m = Math.ceil((f - 29 - i2.toFixed()) / 29.5) + 1;
            i.month = Math.min(m, 12);
            i2.year = i.year;
            i2.month = i.month;
            i2.day = 1;
            i.day = f - i2.toFixed() + 1;
            return i;
        }

        var weekday=new Array("Ahad","Senin","Selasa","Rabu","Kamis","Jumat","Sabtu");
        var monthname=new Array("Januari","Februari","Maret","April","Mei"," Juni","Juli","Agustus","September","Oktober","November","Desember");

        var y = date.getFullYear();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var dow = date.getDay();
        m++;
        fixd=gregToFixed(y, m, d);
        var h=new Hijri(1421, 11, 28);
        h = fixedToHijri(fixd);
```

Then I put this `$('.hijriyah .month').html(h.toString());` to set the value.

The value is: `7 Jumadil Ula 1442`

First for date, `$('.hijriyah .date').html("set to date");` will be: 7
Second for month, `$('.hijriyah .month').html("set to month");` will be: Jumadil Ula
Third for year, `$('.hijriyah .year').html("set to year");` will be: 1442

The function is working good, but I need to separe the value to be 3 parts.

And 1 more, I need to add the day also there,

```
var weekday=new Array("Ahad","Senin","Selasa","Rabu","Kamis","Jumat","Sabtu");
```

Fourth for day, `$('.hijriyah .day').html("set to day");` will be: Selasa (means Tuesday)

How to do that?

Comment: why don't you use "Intl.DateTimeFormat"?

Comment: could you give an example?

Comment: For doing the opposite please see here to convert any Islamic calendar to Gregorian Date without using libraries or complex formulas:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71222556/how-to-convert-any-of-the-5-islamic-hijri-calendars-dates-to-any-of-18-world

Answer (score 1):

The best and available built-in method in Javascript is to use the [Intl.DateTimeFormat() constructor method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat).

Not only will it convert the current 'Gregorian' date to Hijri date but it will convert **any** Gregorian Date to any of the **18 available calendar formats**.

```js
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-u-ca-islamic').format(new Date("2022-02-20")));
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-u-ca-islamic').format(new Date(2030,7,15)));
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-u-ca-islamic',{dateStyle: 'full'}).format(new Date())); // current date
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-u-ca-islamic',{dateStyle: 'medium'}).format(new Date())); // current date
```